# Is this a $\sigma$-algebra (closed under countable union)?

Tags: measure-theory

Could I say that this 
$$
M=\{X\subseteq\Omega=[0,1):x\in X\iff y\in X\}
$$
is an $\sigma$-algebra? I don't see whether it is closed under countable union.
x,y are two singetons of $\Omega$
For example let x=0 y = 0,7 $X_{n}=[1/n, 0,5] n\geq 2$ if we make the infinite countable union of thesse we have $[0,0,5] \notin M$

Comment: What is the problem with proving closure under countable unions? Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: Your latest edit to the question added a mistake, by the way.

Comment: which mistake,please?

Comment: "For example let $x=0$ $y = 0,7$ $X_n=[1/n,0,5]$ $n\ge2$ if we make the infinite countable union of thesse we have $[0,0,5]\notin M$"

Comment: and why is this wrong?

Comment: Look carefully at what you wrote. You should be able to figure the mistake out on your own. Perhaps doing that will help you answer you own question correctly.

Comment: it is something about open and closed extremes of the interval? i tried to continue that way but i wasnt sure.Furthermore not finding a contra-example doesn´t mean that proposition is truth

Comment: @manu: if what you say is true, could you tell me which $X_n$ does $0$ belong to?

Comment: no one but is the limit

Comment: @manu: there's no limit in the definition of $\bigcup_nX_n$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean that $x,y$ are two (fixed) elements of $[0,1)$ and that $M$ is the collection of all sets that either contain both $x$ and $y$ or contain neither $x$ nor $y$.

We will show that $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. It is immediate that $\Omega \in M$ as $\Omega$ contains both $x$ and $y$. Furthermore, if $A \in M$ then $A^c \in M$ since if $A$ contains both $x$ and $y$ then $A^c$ contains neither $x$ nor $y$ and if $A$ contains neither $x$ nor $y$ then $A^c$ contains both $x$ and $y$. So it remains to show that $M$ is closed under countable unions.

Suppose $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots \in M$. We will show that $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in M$. If $A$ does not contain $x$ or $y$ this is clear. Suppose $A$ contains $x$. Then there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in A_n$. Then we have $y \in A_n$, implying $y \in A$. Similarly, $y \in A$ implies $x \in A$. Hence, if $A$ contains $x$ or $y$ then $A$ contains both $x$ and $y$. It follows that $A \in M$, thus $M$ is closed under countable union.